# Media Query Polyfill Performance - IE

Tags: css, media-queries, polyfills

I'm in the early stage of building a site. I'm looking at some design elements that would take advantage of media queries to work properly at smaller screen sizes.

I've no problem with this except that this will be a **small site** and therefore pretty much the only javascript running on it will be a Polyfill for media queries for IE and other limp along browsers.

How much will this impact performance? Are there any proper tests that have been ran?

I ask because I'm in the stage now that if the polyfill affects the performance enough I can tweak the design so I don't have to use them, and also as a thought for future projects.

**Bonus Question:**
If I don't use mobile first but use mobile last, and do `max-width` queries rather than `min`, would I even need a polyfill. If nothing about the page is changing until it's less than 500px wide do I really need to worry about IE not displaying them? Or am I missing some edge cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your bonus question.

If you approach with `max-width` media queries, i don't think you actually need a js solution for IE8 and below. That said, it really depends on what's your site "*breaking point*".

Probably, a user who still has IE7 running won't have an hd screen with 1920x1200 resolution. So keep in mind to make everything work *well* for 800x600 screens without media queries involved.

Personally, i prefer a `min-width` approach, so i can [progressively enhance](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) my site features. But it really depends on your project type/audience.

---

According to [StatCounter's global stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201210-201210-bar), at Sept 2012 ~14% of users still use IE8, and less than 2% IE7.

If you want to serve the best user experience for this 15% (~6 every 100), then you probably need **[respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)**.

I've used and tested it on IE7 and IE8. I didn't notice a difference in performance, but i can't find any benchmark test online.

It's recommended by [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/resources/) and included in [html5boilerplate](http://www.initializr.com/) responsive build, so i'm pretty sure you can...trust it ;-)